# How to repeat each value in a range n times in another range? (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Code:

```
function Repeatn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet() ;

  var mycount = ss.getRange(1, 1).getValue() ;

   for (i=0; i!=7; i++){
    var Pname = ss.getRange(i+5, 3).getValue() ;
    if (Pname ==""){
      break ;
    }
    else {
        for (var k=0; k!=mycount; k++){
        ss.getRange(k+1, 6).setValue(Pname) ;
        }   
    
      }
  
      }

  }
```

[This is what I am trying to achieve][image: 1]
[My current Output][image: 2]

I cannot figure out how to paste each value from column C in column F one after the other. Need help.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array().filter()`, `Array().forEach()` and `Array().push()`, like this:

```js
/**
* Repeats each row in rangeToRepeat timesToRepeat times and
* puts the result in rangeToFill.
*/
function repeatRows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const timesToRepeat = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  const rangeToRepeat = sheet.getRange('C5:C');
  const rangeToFill = sheet.getRange('F1');
  const values = rangeToRepeat.getValues()
    .filter(String);
  const result = [];
  values.forEach(row => {
    let count = timesToRepeat;
    while (count) {
      result.push(row);
      count--;
    }
  });
  rangeToFill
    .offset(0, 0, result.length, result[0].length)
    .setValues(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This solved the problem. I just need to understand the code now as I am new to apps script.